# Django Model Type

Tags: django

My goal is to have a model structure like the below:

```
Course
  Section
    Subsection
```

For each course there can be multiple sections. And each section can have multiple subsections.

```
class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Section(models.Model):
    course = models.OneToOneField(
        Course,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class SubSection(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

   course = models.OneToOneField(
        Course,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

   def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

However, when i test this via the admin, I can create a course, but not a section?

```
# cat course/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Course

admin.site.register(Course)
```

Any ideas on where im going wrong?

Comment: You haven't really explained your problem. Why can't you create a section?

Comment: A `OneToOneField` means that two sections can *not* point to the *same* `Course`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman it is not shown in the adminUI

Comment: Well no because you only registered Course. Why don't you register Section (and Subsection) as well if you want to use them in the admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `Section` was not reqgistered within `admin.py`. 
Adding this, as shown below fixes the issue.

**course/admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Course, Section

admin.site.register(Course)
admin.site.register(Section)
```